# Access Java variable in script tag of ftl file

Tags: freemarker

I am generating a FTL file from java. There is a variable `users` which I have used something like this:

```
  <select id="userlist" class="userList">
    <#list users as user>
        <#if currentAccount?has_content>
            <option value="${user.getName()}" selected>${user.getDisplayName()}</option>
        <#else>
            <option value="${user.getName()}">${user.getDisplayName()}</option>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</select>
```

Now I want to use this `users` variable in script tag. How can I get this?

I tried with `document.getElementById("userlist")` but it gives data in html form

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker runs on the serve-side, then what it generated is sent back to the browser (i.e., back to the client-side), and then JavaScript runs in the browser. So I think that makes your question a JavaScript question, and you can get the currently selected value with `document.getElementById("userlist").value`.